# Unable to Access Remote GUI Programs Using SSH Forwarding

Tags: wireshark

I am running mininet on VMWare and my host machine is Windows10. I am trying to capture the data packets between different virtual host using wireshark.

I have sshed into mininet using teraterm and enabled the X forwarding option. Apart from this i also tried putty with forwarding enabled.

But i am getting an error while invoking wireshark.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have an xserver installed xming from memory was what I used

Comment: Yeah i have installed it. The problem was that i was starting ssh session before initiating the Xming server.